# Newbie .net question - Can't find control?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I have a file called `MasterPages/Wrapper.master.cs` that has the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class vehicles_2011_experience_MasterPages_Wrapper_news : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
                Header_global.Controls.Add(Page.LoadControl("~/en/Controls/Header_global.ascx"));
    }
}
```

When I try to build the solution, I get he error message:

The name "Header_global" does not exist in current context.  The  file `~/en/Controls/Header_global.ascx` DOES EXIST.

So how do I "configure" Visual Studios to  successfully build this solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly are you trying to do?  From this line of code:

```
Header_global.Controls.Add(Page.LoadControl("~/en/Controls/Header_global.ascx"));
```

It looks like you're trying to add a control to itself.  I doubt that's the intent.

The error is basically telling you that there's no declared instance of the glass `Header_global` in the context of that `Page_Load` method.  Does an instance of this header control exist on the master page?  Or are you trying to dynamically create one?

If you're trying to dynamically create one then you need to add it to the page, not to itself.  Generally a good way to do this is to have a `PlaceHolder` control somewhere on the page and to add it to that.  So, after creating the `PlaceHolder` control, the line of code would be something like:

```
PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(Page.LoadControl("~/en/Controls/Header_global.ascx"));
```

Comment: Hey David, forgive me if I'm totally confused, but the code I posted is from my masterpage.  So it looks like my master page is trying to load a control.   I inherited this .net project from someone else, so trying to learn .net right now.

Comment: @John: There are a number of ways to add a control to a page.  The most direct way, in Visual Studio, is to edit the page in Design View and just drag the control (in this case, the `.ascx` file in the Solution Explorer) onto the page.  You can more accurately manipulate the control's layout back in the HTML View once it's been added.  To dynamically load a control from code, as this line of code is attempting, requires a place to put it.  You can add it to the page itself, but it's better to add it to an existing control (such as a `PlaceHolder`).

Comment: Hey David, I think I'm starting to understand.  I see in the mark up of my Wrapper.master the line `<asp:PlaceHolder ID="Header_global" runat="server" />`.  So does that mean it should now be accessible from my Page_Load via the Header_global object?

Comment: @John: That sounds like it should be the case.  However, note that naming a `PlaceHolder` instance as a variable called `Header_global` will probably get confusing and unintuitive if `Header_global` is also the name of a class (the class for your user control).  The compiler probably won't like that.  It would be better to change the `PlaceHolder`'s ID to something like `pageHeader` or `phHeader` or something meaningful.

Comment: Is there any reason why if `<asp:PlaceHolder ID="Header_global" runat="server" />` exists in the Wrapper.master markup, it is still "unaccessible" through the Page_Load code?   When I type Header_global(period), visual studios doesn't show me any autocomplete/intellisense to indicate it recognizes it.  I still get the compilation error.  Is this a matter of me not setting up the solution files/*.csproj file correctly?

Comment: @John: Well, aside from the issue I mentioned where the compiler confuses the variable name with the class name... Having the tag present in the markup is only half the equation.  For the code to reference that object, it needs to be declared/instantiated somewhere.  Usually this is done for you in a partial class in the page's designer.cs file.  But, depending on your version of .NET, Visual Studio, and potentially a number of other factors local to your project, it may not have been done for you.  _Somewhere_ in the scope of the page's class should be `protected PlaceHolder Header_global`.

Comment: Hey David, this problem is also happening with my Textbox type fields.  So for example, on another ascx file, I have  <asp:TextBox ID="emailTbx" runat="server" CssClass="popup_input"></asp:TextBox>.  But in my codebehind, I can't access the object....

Comment: Oh for some reason, I right clicked the project in solution explorer, and chose "Convert to Web Application"...that got rid of ALL my errors.